# Startup/first query extremely slow

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

It takes a while (3 minutes+) to 'create/compile' my DbContext. The web server starts in about 5 seconds, but when I do the first query to my database, EF 2.0 has to 'build/create/compile' the database in memory or something, I think? The next requests are almost instant. This was a Database First creation of the DbContext, the database already exists in MSSQL and has data. The DbContext contains about 500 DbSet's with relations.

Is there a way to speed this up by doing the 'creation(mapping?)' of my Entity Framework's DbContext before running the web server (at developmenttime), create the file/mappings it needs, so the first request is fast too?

Comment: Lazy loading does not yet exist on Entity Framework Core 2.0? Every time the application is started, not every request.

Comment: If you host with IIS, have a look at the following: https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/auto-start-asp-net-applications-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series or https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/795265/IIS-Asp-net-warm-up-Auto-Start-Application otherwise, your webserver might support comparable techniques. Anyway, it's something the webserver has to initiate. Your app just doesn't execute anything before the webserver decides, so there is no way to do it in code alone.

Comment: The web application itself starts in about 5 seconds, which is acceptable. It's the first query through EF Core 2.0 that takes 3 minutes+. If I just show a HTML page, it is loaded after about 5 seconds. The same if I use ADO.NET, the query is shown after 2 seconds. It's the first query (even a simple db.Articles.FirstOrDefault()) that takes 3 minutes+, the subsequent query (any query) takes a normal 100ms or something.

Comment: Yes, so what? You need to issue your first (dummy) query in some startup code instead of waiting for the first user request. If you place it into the app startup, the startup will become unacceptable, so you need to place it in a client-independent warmup code

Comment: Since I'm trying to debug (in development), I'm asking if this 'first dummy query' time can be lowere. Because probably EF is bootstrapping itself, which I'm asking if the result of this bootstrap can be cached, so that EF does not need to rebuild the whole bootstrap every run and instead read the cached version.

Comment: As far as I know, caching was available in EF6 but was dropped for EF Core because it created to much development overhead

Answer (score 0):

In general this is normal Entity framework behavior by default, but from other side of cause there are some ways to resolve this course of things.

For example you can try:

- disable database initialization
- using pre-generation views
- "warm" loading

Please try to read this articles:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh949853(v=vs.113).aspx
- https://www.fusonic.net/en/blog/3-steps-for-fast-entityframework-6.1-code-first-startup-performance/
- https://www.fusonic.net/en/blog/ef-cache-deployment/